# Cypher query to give path length as a parameter for variable length relationships which is the result of previous sub query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For the following cypher query , how to limit path length by giving "cnt" as a parameter which is the output of previous query passed to next query using "with" clause.

`match ()-[r:contents|next_seq]->(n:word) where r.seqid={seqid} 
 with count(distinct n) as cnt
 match p=((a:word)-[rels:next_seq*cnt]->(b:word)) 
 WHERE ALL( rt in rels WHERE rt.seqid={seqid} 
 return b.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, the `cypher` does not allow to use a variable as the path length.

If you use a version of `neo4j` >= 3 you can use [`apoc path expander`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_path_expander):

```
match ()-[r:contents|next_seq]->(n:word) where r.seqid={seqid} 
with count(distinct n) as cnt
match (a:word)-[rels:next_seq {seqid: {seqid}}]->(:word))
with distinct a
call apoc.path.expand( a, 'next_seq', '+word', 1, cnt ) yield path
with path WHERE ALL( rt in relationships(path) where rt.seqid={seqid} )
return last(nodes(path)).name as name
```